# How do I keep track of top 5 values that I have stored in a Map till now while iterating a continuous stream?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a Java Map that has String for Keys and Integers for values. While iterating through a continuous stream and adding elements(or new Key-Value pairs) to the Map, I only want to keep the highest 5 Values in the Map. Essentially, if I encounter an integer that is bigger than any of the 5 "Values" in the map, I'll remove the key with the smallest value from the map and add the current value by using a different key. Duplicate values are allowed in the map.

For example, if my current map is as shown below:

**| Key | Value |**
| Key1   | 1   |
| Key2   | 2   |
| Key3   | 2   |
| Key4   | 3   |
| Key5   | 4   |

And I encounter a new Key-Value Pair (or element) e.g. (Key6,5), my new map should be as shown below:
**| Key | Value |**
| Key2   | 2   |
| Key3   | 2   |
| Key4   | 3   |
| Key5   | 4   |
| Key6   | 5   |

How do I achieve this in the most efficient way possible?

If I keep iterating over the "Values" every time I encounter a new Key-Value pair, solving this is easy. However that affects my performance if the number of elements in the stream is huge.

Comment: Generally to achieve goal try to use TreeMap which will sort elements by itself automatically (Add comparator as a constructor parameter, when creating TreeMap instance), and try to look at the restrict count of elements in the map by 5, alternatively, you can remove the last element by hand, lets say

Answer (score 0):

Since you're only adding/remove one key-value pair at a time, just create an extra variable that holds the key of the current lowest value. Then, you just compare to that item on each new streamed key-value pair. Something like this:

```
// Get instantiated and populated somewhere else.
Map map;
ArrayList<String> keys;
int minValue;

void processStreamValue(String key, int value) {
    if (value == minValue) {
        map.put(key, value);
        keys.add(key);
        return;
    }

    if (value > minValue) {
        map.put(key, value);

        foreach (k in keys) { map.remove(k); }
        keys.clear();
        keys.add(key, value);
        minValue = value;
    }
}
```